# Calculus airplane related rates problem ( cosine rule)

Tags: calculus, differential, related-rates

[image]

> A student has test his airplane and he is far from the airplane for $5$ meter.He start to test his airplane by letting his airplane to move $60$ degree from the horizontal plane with constant velocity for $120$ meter per minute.Find the rate of distance between the student and the plane when the plane is moving 60 degree from the horizontal plane for $10$ meter in the air ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?  Are you stuck on some particular step? Is the answer wrong? Please note that questions showing no effort tend to be voted down and/or closed.

Comment: I am stuck with the problem I have tried to do it but I cannot solve for it. Please help me

Comment: @jaychay I saw the change just now, Please give me more time to respond. At present I deleted my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the cosine rule, write the distance $a$ from the observer. Note that $b=5$ and $c=120t$. The angle $\theta$, as seen in the figure is $180^\circ-60^\circ=120^\circ$. You can now calculate $a(t)$. What they ask is the derivative of this quantity with respect to time $t$:$$\frac{d a(t)}{dt}$$

Comment: Thank you so much sir !!!

Answer (score 0):

At first we find displacements as triangle side lengths.

Velocities are in proportion to the sides. Dynamic triangles/ parallelogram of displacements, velocities and accelerations all have a similarity.

[image]

Absolute velocity of the plane is proportional to $a$ . Velocity of plane P
relative to the student S is proportional to $c$.

Ratio of  velocity to side length to $ 120/10=12 sec^{-1}$

So the relative velocity $= 12\times 5 \sqrt3=  103.923 \;$ meters/min.

Comment: Everything is right except your last statement "Velocities are in proportion to the sides". That would imply that the length of $c$ is directly proportional to time since the length of $a$ is $v_a t$. But the length of $c$ is is not. At $t=0$ you have $c=b$.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! It's really help me a lot